# How to manipulate div style with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
        </title>
        <style>
        div
        {
            width:5em;
            height:5em;
            background-color:yellow;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="div">
        </div>
        <script>
        window.onload = function() {
        var x;
        x = document.getElementByID("div");
        x.style.width = '9em' ;
        x.style.backgroundColor = "green";
    };

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

What im doing wrong ? I want to change div properties like width or background color with javascript but it's not working.

Comment: `getElementByID` should be `getElementById`

Comment: It is always a good idea to look in the JavaScript console of the browser, i.e. for Google Chrome press CTRL-SHIFT-I and select the console tab. There you'll see an error message like "Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementByID is not a function" which points to the solution, as Suresh already mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

change `getElementByID` to `getElementById`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
        </title>
        <style>
        div
        {
            width:5em;
            height:5em;
            background-color:yellow;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="div">
        </div>
        <script>
        window.onload = function() {
        var x;
        x = document.getElementById("div");
        x.style.width = '9em' ;
        x.style.backgroundColor = "green";
    };

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're using `getElementByID`. The correct method is `getElementById`.

Your script should look something like this:

```
window.onload = function() {
  var x;
  x = document.getElementById("div");
  x.style.width = '9em';
  x.style.backgroundColor = "green";
};
```

Comment: My apologies. Corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

**JavaScript** Syntax Error ! Here is the update...........

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>
    </title>
    <style>
    /* div {
        width: 5em;
        height: 5em;
        background-color: yellow;
    } */
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="div">
    </div>
    <script>
    
        var x = document.getElementById("div");
        x.style.width = "9em";
        x.style.height = "9em";
        x.style.display = "block";
        x.style.backgroundColor = "green";

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Always better to explain what you've changed, rather than expect people to compare your code with the original to find - in this case - a single character change

Answer (score 0):

Change getElementByID to getElementById.

```
window.onload = function() {
  var x;
  x = document.getElementById("div");
  x.style.width = '9em';
  x.style.backgroundColor = "green";
};
```

If you want to search by the tag name, you can directly use getElementsByTagName("div") instead of assigning an id of the value div. But bear in my mind that it will return all div elements; i.e. a collection of elements.